# Can sound be off every time I power off?

Tags: macos, mac, audio

I would like to config my Mac (10.8.5) to turn the sound off every time I power it off so that when I power it back on it is silent and doesn't produce that funny boot sound.  Can that be done?

The thing is, I come in to work late and, if I had the sound on before I turned the laptop off (e.g. watched YouTube at home) and forgot to turn the sound off before, my whole cube farm at work resonates and they are like "this guy just came in to work"...  LOL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the audio value on boot using this:

```
sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00
```

<sup>`00` will set to 0% volume (i.e. mute)</sup>

You can reset this by resetting the NVRAM by booting with ⌘⌥PR, or running

```
sudo nvram -d SystemAudioVolume
```

Comment: is this a one time command that modifies a persisted setting (i.e. doesn't have to be execed in every session)?

Comment: @amphibient This is a persistent setting, being set in the NVRAM. Providing you don't reset your NVRAM, this setting will remain.

Comment: didn't work, i ran it as my admin but not superuser.  should i run it as root under `sudo`?

Comment: @amphibient Yes, you'll need to run it as root.

Comment: actually, I take it back, i just went through my history and i did run it under `sudo`.  i turned the sound on, then powered off, when i powered back on, the boot sound played.  so it didn't work :(

Comment: @amphibient Reboot, then run `sudo nvram -p | grep SystemAudioVolume` — what do you get?

Comment: SystemAudioVolume %d7

Comment: @amphibient Hmm, that's not what it should be. Reboot, holding ⌘⌥PR until the *second* chime (to reset the NVRAM), then run the original command. Reboot, and the sound should be mute.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to turn off the startup sound is to use StartNinja.

You can download from here:

https://www.allvu.com/start-ninja

Comment: What does it do - just act as a cover for the command in @grgarside's answer?

Comment: And the web page says it does to work with iMacs

Comment: this works with macbooks, I didn't test with iMac. I don't know how it implements the functionality.