# How to turn off boot up chime on late 2013 mac pro?

Tags: startup, mac-pro

I use my new late 2013 Mac Pro in Windows only.
But, I'd like to disable the bootup chime. How can I do this?

Comment: Windows means Bootcamp in your case I assume?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can sound be off every time I power off?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119996/can-sound-be-off-every-time-i-power-off)

Comment: Do you have Windows and Mac OS X or just Windows?

Comment: Not a duplicate since it is only concerned with a mac pro using only windows.  Kevin Grabher answer works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boot chime is always as loud as the volume when you turn off your mac. There are tools for mac to disable it I believe. I don't know wether those affect windows as well.

**EDIT: It seems the volume you set in windows has no control over the volume when booting again. So if you only use windows anyhow, boot into Mac OS (by holding the alt-key when booting). Then set the volume to zero (turn it down, don't use the mute key). You're Mac shouldn't chime anymore.**

Comment: Consider making this a comment since it is not quite a answer.

Comment: To make it more answer-y, if you don't forget to mute your sound when turning off your machine, it won't chime when you boot it again ;)

Comment: Thanks Kevin... that was seemingly obvious, I should have figured it out myself.  Much appreciated.